# How to solve collision response in 2d space?

Tags: collision-detection, game-engine, game-physics, rigid-bodies

I have got collision result from collision algorithm. The collision result contains the contact points from two colliding bodies, separation length and collision normal vector.

[collision info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rinc3.png)

bodyA: rectangle ABCD

bodyB: line segment EF

normal: the normal vector of collision surface

contact point pair1: point D and point G

contact point pair2: point C and point H

separation length: 1

I create a struct to save collision information:

```cpp
using real = double;
    struct Collision
    {
        bool isColliding = false;
        Body* bodyA = nullptr;
        Body* bodyB = nullptr;
        std::vector<PointPair> contactList;
        Vector2 normal;
        real penetration = 0;
    };
```

Then I create a collision solver class and solver data struct:

```cpp
    struct SolverData
    {
        Collision info;
        real effectiveMassNormal = 0;
        real bias = 0;
        Vector2 ra;
        Vector2 rb;
    };
    class CollisionSolver
    {
        public:
            void add(const Collision& info);
            void prepare(const real& dt);
            void solveVelocity(const real& dt);
            void solvePosition(const real& dt);
        private:
            std::vector<SolverData> m_dataList;
            std::vector<Collision> m_list;
    };
```

In function `void prepare()` , I just calculate the effective mass of contact point like this:

```cpp
void prepare(const real& dt)
{
    for (Collision& info : m_list)
    {
        for (auto& contact : info.contactList)
        {
            Vector2 ra = contact.pointA - info.bodyA->position();
            Vector2 rb = contact.pointB - info.bodyB->position();
            Vector2 normal = info.normal;

            real im_a = info.bodyA->inverseMass();
            real im_b = info.bodyB->inverseMass();
            real ii_a = info.bodyA->inverseInertia();
            real ii_b = info.bodyB->inverseInertia();

            real ra_n = ra.cross(normal);
            real rb_n = rb.cross(normal);

            real ra_t = ra.cross(tangent);
            real rb_t = rb.cross(tangent);

            real inv_dt = 1.0 / dt;
                
            SolverData data;
            data.bias = -m_bias * inv_dt * info.penetration;

            //effective mass = 1.0 / k-matrix
            data.effectiveMassNormal = 1.0 /
                (im_a + ii_a * ra_n * ra_n + im_b + ii_b * rb_n * rb_n);

            data.info = info;
            data.ra = ra;
            data.rb = rb;
            
            m_dataList.emplace_back(data);
        }
    }
}
```

In function solveVelocity(), I have calculated the velocity of contact point and the relative velocity, then substitute into the formula Jv+b=0 to get the magnitude of impulse:

```cpp
void solve(const real& dt)
{
    for(int i = 0;i < m_iteration;i++)
        {
            for (SolverData& data : m_dataList)
            {
                Vector2 vB = data.info.bodyB->velocity() + 
     Vector2::crossProduct(data.info.bodyB->angularVelocity(), data.rb);

                Vector2 vA = data.info.bodyA->velocity() + 
     Vector2::crossProduct(data.info.bodyA->angularVelocity(), data.ra);
                Vector2 rv = vB - vA;
                
                real rv_n = rv.dot(data.info.normal);
                real lambda_n = data.effectiveMassNormal * (rv_n - data.bias);
                
                Vector2 impulseNormal = lambda_n * data.info.normal;
                
                data.info.bodyA->applyImpulse(impulseNormal, data.ra);
                data.info.bodyB->applyImpulse(-impulseNormal, data.rb);
                
            }
        }

        m_dataList.clear();
        m_list.clear();
}
```

I think everything is clear, but I get the wrong result:

[wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwEI5.gif)

The mass of bodyA is 100kg, and I consider bodyB as ground with infinity mass.
The width and height of rectangle are same number, 1 meter.

Position of bodyA is (0, -2) and bodyB is (0, -8).

The unit I use is Kg/M/N.

How to solve the wrong answer?

Comment: Not enough information is provided to effectively answer. How are forces estimated now? What does the overlap look like over several time steps. Is there a consideration for the impacting velocity or just the penetration? Is it a spring model or an impulse model?

Comment: Just impulse model and mass of every rigid body is considered as 1.0f. After the collision detection class return the contact points and penetration depth and separation direction, I just simply add a force proportional to the depth to separate two rigid body at next time step. However, it seems at next time step, it doesn't separate completely and still remains a little overlapping area.

Comment: If you knew the contact impulse **J** and the time step **h** then the average force is **F=J/h** and that should reverse the motion of the contact. Please [edit] the question with more details (and code) on the contact handling side.

Comment: Also [read this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/95883) on how to get a link to `imgur` image (not the post) and embed in post above with an exclamation point infront of the link. For example `![description](http://i.imgur.com/12345.png)`. For me the link above is blocked.

Comment: I am sorry for the blocked link. I will them write more detail about my question. Thanks for reply!

Comment: Well I expect you are going to fix the post then.

Comment: I have fixed the detail. Hope you could understand it.

Comment: When you link an image add an exclamation point in-front of the link. `[regular link](http://url.here)` vs `![image link](http://url.here)`.

Comment: Also [read this great reference](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~baraff/sigcourse/notesd2.pdf) on 3D body collisions for games.

Comment: Okay! Fixed image link

Comment: Your [effective mass normal](https://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?%5Clarge%20%5Cmu%20%3D%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Csum_%7Bi%3Da%2Cb%7D%20%5Cleft%28%20%5Ctfrac%7B1%7D%7Bm_i%7D&plus;%5Chat%7Bn%7D%5Ccdot%20%28%5Cvec%7Br%7D_i%20%5Ctimes%20%5Cmathrm%7BI%7D_i%5E%7B-1%7D%20%28%5Chat%7Bn%7D%5Ctimes%20%5Cvec%7Br%7D_i%20%29%20%29%20%5Cright%20%29%7D) is correct for 2D cases.